# send data http to webserver no result

Tags: android

i create a simple tutorial send data to server

i create a button inside onCreate

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click

                postData();
            }
        });
```

here is my code to send the data

```
public void postData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.www.www/hama/test123.php");

        //This is the data to send
        String MyName = "adil"; //any data to send

        try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", MyName));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

        //This is the response from a php application
        String reverseString = response;
        Toast.makeText(this, "response" + reverseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "CPE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "IOE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

        }//end postData()
```

when i try to press the button there is no result in webserver when i try to refresh the page.
the page is blank and no result.

here is my php code

```
<?php

//code to reverse the string

$reversed = strrev($_POST["action"]);

echo $reversed;

?>
```

how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, **NEVER** perform network actions on the UI Thread. It will make your app unresponsive.

```
String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```

that actually returns an HttpResponse, not a String. Do this instead:

```
final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get, localContext);

final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
final InputStream is = entity.getContent();
final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "ISO-8859-1");
final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = "";
String responseFromServer = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     responseFromServer += line;
}
```

`responseFromServer` will contain your server response.

And please, next time at least try doing some `ex.printStackTrace()` on your catch blocks so you know what's going on.

Comment: still no result @santirivera92

Comment: Does any exception come up? Are you sure that your php code is right?

Comment: its something wrong about my web browser or my code php. when i try to catch the post to database it works, but in refresh page php, the data wont show, i try with your code it works too. thanks. @santirivera92